# How to handle the basic authentication (Rest API- Post Request) with selenium webdriver code?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, postman

How to handle basic authentication of Rest-API using selnium webdriver and java

Comment: you should be able to pass basic auth credentials in the url: http://user:pass@example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have more than one solution:

1- You can use user:password@yourURL.com (Make sure that username or password doesn't contain any special characters).

2- You can add a header key "Authorization" to your request with credEncodedString as a  value for that key:
byte[] credentials = (userName + ":" + password).getBytes();
String credEncodedString = "Basic " + Base64Encoder.encode(credentials);